# How to enable smooth shading in Eevee?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, smooth

My object in Solid Mode:

[image]

The same object in Render Preview (with Eevee):

[image]

I didn't change anything. The only button I pressed is to set my viewport shading to Render Preview. And the smooth shading was gone.

I suppose I need to enable smooth shading for Eevee somehow? Right Click -> Smooth Shading doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please share this object?

Comment: It's bought so i can't legally just upload it... I'll try to reproduce this problem with a cube or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the problem. I need to put a Normal Map node between the Image Texture and the normal socket.

[image]